# Vertical spacing after user-defined environment

Tags: spacing, sectioning

In my lectures, I define an `\example` command for typesetting… examples a bit separated from the paragraph content. Sometimes they contain text, sometime tables, etc. For some reasons, I use `\subparagraph` in the definition of my command, so I need to add some vertical spacing after it in order to separate from following text. As I don’t want to add even more when already using a `vmode` environment, I set that conditionally for `hmode` only. My issue arise when there is a sectioning command after an example, like below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\example}[1]{\subparagraph{Exemple :\hspace{-1.25ex}} #1\ifhmode\par\leavevmode\fi}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Bad spacing}

Some text.

\example{Some example text.}

\subsection*{Correct spacing}

Some more text.

\example{Some example text.}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\subsection*{Test}

Yet another text.

\example{Some example text.}

Final text.

\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image: code output]

As you can see, there is too much vertical spacing after the first “Example”, which I correct in the second one using a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`.

The issue also happens when there is a second example after the first one, but I think this is the same issue because of the sectioning nature of my `\example` command.

Is there a way to have the correct spacing in all cases (including when there is a `vmode` env inside an `\example{}`, e.g. `center`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to [Yannis Lazarides answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616738/56823), the actual solution is this:

```
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\subparagraph{Exemple :\hspace{-1.25ex}} #1\ifhmode\vskip\baselineskip\fi}
```

i.e. using `\vskip` instead of `\par` so that the vertical spacing is merged when not required.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too sure, what you are asking exactly, but here are some suggestions:

1. When TeX sees a character, it will start in horizontal mode, so there is no need for you to check for `vmode` or `hmode`.
2. Use `\addvspace` for vertical spacing.

To be honest personally I would use a package such as `exsheets` or if your lectures include maths, I would use the `amsthm` package to create the example environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength\exampletop
\setlength\exampletop\baselineskip
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \par
  \addvspace\exampletop
  \leavevmode
  \bgroup
  \sffamily
  \bfseries 
   Example:
  \egroup
   #1
   \par
   \vskip10pt
 }

\begin{document}
    
\subsection{Test}
    
Final text.
    
\subparagraph{Example:}Subparagraph
    
\subparagraph{Example:}Subparagraph
    
\example{ \lipsum[1]}
    
\example{Some example text.
My new equation
$$a = b +  c$$}
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some time I have a `center` environment in my examples (e.g. for a `tabular`), and I don’t want the additional spacing in this case. Hence the check for `hmode`, to only add spacing in other cases.
Maybe my question wasn’t clear enough, but you gave me the right track: `\vskip`. This is exactly what I needed, I didn’t knew the difference between `\vspace` and this one, the fact the spacing is “merged” with `\vskip` is what I wanted.